# Apache Rewrite Engine redirect all request to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a PHP web application on a Apache Web Server.

The path to to web application on the Server is: `/var/www/html/intern/organisation/example_app`

The URL to the web application is:
`https://www.example.de/org1/intern/example_app/`

I want, that all request, e.g. `https://www.example.de/org1/intern/example_app/view1/` are redirected to

```
https://www.example.de/org1/intern/example_app/index.php
```

On my local XAMPP Server I use following .htaccess file, that works for that purpose:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example_app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

But I have no idea, how that file should look like on the Server? I also use a httpd.conf on the server. I wondering, if that file interferes with the `.htaccess` file, that lies below: `/var/www/html/intern/organisation/example_app/`

Has anyone an idea how to config the rewriting on the Server?

Comment: Where are these `.htaccess` file(s) located? Do you have multiple `.htaccess` files (in other directories)? The file-path and URL-path on the server don't appear to match? Do you have additional rewriting (or `Alias`) configured in the server config, or is `example_app` in the file-path a different directory to `example_app` in the URL-path?

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file in the `/org1/intern/example_app/` subdirectory should look like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You can then use the same `.htaccess` file locally and on the live server, providing it goes in the `example_app/` subdirectory.

Providing the `.htaccess` file is located in the same directory as the `index.php` file you are wanting to rewrite to then you don't need the `RewriteBase` directive.

The `DirectoryIndex` directive is likely already set to `index.php` in the server config, so it may not be required here, but for completeness it should be included. It is required for when the application directory itself is requested (ie. `https://www.example.de/org1/intern/example_app/`).

Note that this is an "internal redirect", or more commonly referred to as a "rewrite". If you simply say "redirect" then that implies an "external (HTTP) redirect", which is something else entirely.

---

> I wondering, if that file interferes with the `.htaccess file`, that lies below: `/var/www/html/intern/organisation/example_app/`

Multiple `.htaccess` files (and the server config) can conflict. However, mod_rewrite directives in a child config (in the same *context*, ie. *directory*) will completely override mod_rewrite directives in the parent config (by default).

---

*Aside:* (or possibly not)

> The path to to web application on the Server is: `/var/www/html/intern/organisation/example_app`
>
> The URL to the web application is: `https://www.example.de/org1/intern/example_app/`

Although, slightly confusing, the file-path and URL-path don't appear to match? Do you have additional rewriting or `Alias` configured in the server config, or is `example_app` in the file-path a different directory to `example_app` in the URL-path?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the detailed answers. The Rewriting Rules were not the problem.

The problem was simple. The whole .htaccess didn't word because I had to activate AllowOveride on the httpd.conf.

Comment: the URL ist different from the file-path. Because there is a CMS on another server for our whole organisation. My apps on my Server are Part of that CMS. I don't know how that technically works, because someone else is responsible for the CMS.

Comment: "The Rewriting Rules were not the problem." - although the rewrite rules you posted in the question would not have worked on the "server" due to the _incorrect_ `RewriteBase` directive, as mentioned in my answer.